# How to extract the numbers from a filename

Tags: linux, bash, awk, filenames

How do I get only the numbers from a filename in another directory? Using ONLY `sed`  `awk` or `bash`? Assume it can be any arbitrary length but the format will always be ABC1234.

If I have a file name `ABC1311.crs` then I only want `1311`.
I've tried:

```
number=`awk -F '[]' '{print $2}' $data/ABC123.crs
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems like an odd requirement, but to extract digits from arbitrary filenames, you could use parameter expansion to remove anything from the filename that's not a digit:

```
for f in *
do
  printf '%s\n' "${f//[![:digit:]]/}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `grep`:

```
grep -Eo '[0-9]+' file.txt
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention I can only use sed awk and bash

Comment: Why are you restricted to those commands? Is this homework?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the numbers by the following command:

```
echo * | grep -o '[[:digit:]]*'
```

You can replace `echo *` by `ls` if you like.

If you just want to use `awk`, then you can do the following:

```
\ls | awk 'match($0, /[[:digit:]]+/) {print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)}'
```

`\ls` will list all the files in your directory but `awk` will print only the first set of numbers.  If you have files with multiple numeric strings (such as `2043x924_fjnndkk.jpg`), it will only output `2043`.

Use `\ls` if your `ls` is aliased to something; otherwise, a plain `ls` will suffice.  In my case, I have aliased `ls` to `ls -s` (among other options) and so, always get the size printed which interferes with this command.

Comment: I can only use sed awk or bash

Comment: @kevo885 There is no compelling reason to impose that restriction as far as I can see. A Unix system always has both `grep` and `ls`.