# awk extract numbers from a string

Tags: awk

There are multiple related Questions, seems they don't use `awk` to solve the problem.

- [Extracting positive/negative floating-point numbers from a string](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/290974/extracting-positive-negative-floating-point-numbers-from-a-string)
- [How to extract the numbers from a filename](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/616249/how-to-extract-the-numbers-from-a-filename)

```
echo "blah foo123bar234blah" | egrep -o '([0-9]+)'
```

returns

```
123
234
```

But

```
echo "blah foo123bar234blah" | 
    awk '{ match($0,/([0-9]+)/,m); print m[0], m[1],m[2]}'
```

returns `123 123` and

```
echo "blah foo123bar234blah" | 
    awk '{ match($0,/([0-9]+).+([0-9]+)/,m); print m[0], m[1],m[2]}'
```

returns   `123bar234 123 4`

In [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html), in the section: **match(string, regexp [, array])**, the example is:

```
echo foooobazbarrrrr |
    gawk '{ match($0, /(fo+).+(bar*)/, arr); print arr[1], arr[2]}'
```

Which returns `foooo barrrrr`.

So how can I extract multiple numbers from a string using awk (equivalent of `grep -o`)?

Comment: The problem is that `.+` between the two numeric matches. It soaks up digits too. Personally, I would: `tmp = $0; gsub(/[^0-9]/, " ", tmp); split(tmp, m);`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ echo "blah foo123bar234blah" |
    awk -v RS='[0-9]+' '$0=RT'
123
234
```

With any awk (and retaining the original regexp instead of negating it as that's only easy with a simple bracket expression and not a robust general approach):

```
$ echo "blah foo123bar234blah" |
    awk -v FS='\n' '{gsub(/[0-9]+/,FS"&"FS); for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) print $i}'
123
234
```

or:

```
$ echo "blah foo123bar234blah" |
    awk '{ while (match($0,/[0-9]+/) ) {print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)} }'
123
234
```

Comment: great. When RS is a single character, RT contains the same single character. However, when RS is a regular expression, RT contains the actual input text that matched the regular expression.  https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/gawk-split-records.html

Comment: @EdMorton. `echo "blah foo123bar234blah" |      awk -v FS='\n' '{gsub(/[0-9]+/,FS); for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=1) print i,$i}'` I figured how `gsub` do. But I am not sure what does `FS"&"FS` do.

Comment: @Mark What I'm doing with `gsub(/[0-9]+/,FS"&"FS)` puts a newline before and after each number. Since I'm using newline (which can't be present in the current input record since I'm also using newline as the RS) as the FS, doing that means that every even numbered field is then a number.

Comment: now I get it.
.  An & in the replacement text is
                               replaced with the text that was actually matched.  Use \& to get a literal &.  (This must  be  typed
                               as  "\\&";  see  GAWK: Effective AWK Programming for a fuller discussion of the rules for ampersands
                               and backslashes in the replacement text of sub(), gsub(), and gensub().)

Comment: No, not "any awk": [support gsub](http://www.shelldorado.com/articles/awkcompat.html).

Comment: The only awk that doesn't support gsub() is old, broken awk which doesn't support much of anything and must never be used. If you were going to specifically mention excluding old, broken awk from answers then you'll have to do so in almost every answer which is a complete waste of time. Don't use old, broken awk, that is all.

Answer (score 4):

The `match()` function performs a *single* match of your regular expression.  To find each run of digits using regular expression matching with `match()` in GNU `awk`, you have to loop.

```c
{
    str = $0
    while (match(str,"[0-9]+",a)) {
        print a[0]
        str = substr(str,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
}
```

We are only interested in `a[0]` here, as we don't use parentheses in our regular expression. We don't use parentheses in our expression because we don't need them.  We had possibly needed parentheses if we had wanted to match a known number of integers with a single expression (e.g. `([0-9]+)[^0-9]+([0-9]+)`, etc.), but in this exercise we don't really know how many integers there might be.

Or, with standard `awk`,

```c
{
    str = $0
    while (match(str,"[0-9]+")) {
        print substr(str,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        str = substr(str,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
}
```

This matches runs of consecutive digits in the string in `str`. For each match, the matching string is printed and the part of `str` that is no longer interesting to look at is removed using `substr()`.

Testing:

```bsh
$ echo 'blah foo123bar234blah' | gawk '{ str = $0; while (match(str,"[0-9]+",a)) { print a[0]; str = substr(str,RSTART+RLENGTH) } }'
123
234
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `gsub()` function of `awk` and transform every occurence of "substrings that to not consist of digits" into single spaces, and then use the `split()` function to split the resulting string at the whitespace. This behaves just as field splitting on the default `FS` variable and discards leading and trailing "empty fields":

```
awk '{gsub(/[^0-9]+/," ");n=split($0,a);for (i=1;i<=n;i++) print a[i]}'
```

So, for your example:

```
~$ echo "blah foo123bar234blah" | awk '{gsub(/[^0-9]+/," ");n=split($0,a);for (i=1;i<=n;i++) print a[i]}'
123
234
```

Answer (score 2):

To extracts English *`0-9`* digits, using GNU awk for the FPAT:

```
awk -v FPAT='[0-9]+' -v OFS='\n' '$1=$1""'
```

or with any awk:

```
awk -F'[^0-9]+' '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i+0==$i) print $i }' infile
```

or specifically using the match() function (no benefit BTW, since we know we filter out only digits in `[^0-9]+`, so everything else are just digits but yes, in order to avoid printing empty fields it's useful but not etter than `$i+0==$i` as above):

```
awk -F'[^0-9]+' '{
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if (match($i, /[0-9]+/)) print $i
    }
}' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to just extract numbers (natural numbers and zero in the following example!), you may define anything else as field separators:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="[^0-9]+"}
     {printf $1 ; for (i=2 ; i<=NF ; i++) { printf " "$i} ; printf "\n"}'
```

(added some formatting so it returns space separated entries for on one line per record)

Comment: Why `printf $1` is null/empty? this part I am not sure.  I understand αғsнιη's solution.

Comment: @Mark Anything but a  digit is field separator. If your string is `foo123bar` the first separator is `foo` and thus the first field empty (no entry before `foo`). For `123foo456bar`, the first field would be `123`.

Answer (score 1):

And also another option using GNU `awk` for `patsplit()`:

```
echo "blah foo123bar234blah" | awk 'patsplit($0, a, /[[:digit:]]+/) { for (i in a) printf "%d\n", a[i]}'
123
234
```

Answer (score 0):

why make it so complex with all that FPAT and patsplit and while(match()) -

just this suffices :

```
 echo 'blah foo123bar234blah' \
 \
 | mawk2 'BEGIN { FS="[^0-9]+"; OFS=ORS; ORS="" } NF=NF'

123
234
```